# Python enum class doesn't match itself when imported from another module

Tags: python, enums, python-import

Here's a fun one:

I have a python enumeration created in one module and then used both in that module and in another module. When I import the enumeration in the second module, it ends up not matching the value imported in the first module. I want to pass the value "KnownComputers.KILLDEVIL" into the first module from the second module, but when I compare the value I pass in against "KnownComputers.KILLDEVIL" they compare not equal. Weird!

`servers.py` lives in `foo_module/servers.py`:

```
from enum import Enum

class KnownComputers(Enum):
    KILLDEVIL = "killdevil"
    LONGLEAF = "longleaf"
    DOGWOOD = "dogwood"
    WIGGINS = "wiggins"
    ANDREWS_LAPTOP = "andrews_laptop"
    CATHYS_DESKTOP = "cathys_desktop"
```

used in that module to make a decision:
`decision.py` in `foo_module/decision.py`:

```
from servers import KnownComputers

def func( identifier ):
    comp = identifier.which_computer()
    if comp == KnownComputers.KILLDEVIL:
        print( "Found killdevil!")
    else:
        print( "Found nothing!")
```

(and there's an empty `__init__.py` in `foo_module/`)

Then in my second module, in `testbed.py` of `bar_module/testbed.py`

```
from foo_module.servers import KnownComputers
import foo_module.decide

class killdevil_ident:
    def which_computer(self):
        return KnownComputers.KILLDEVIL

ki = killdevil_ident()
foo_module.decide.func(ki)
```

What I would expect to see printed is `Found killdevil!` but what is actually printed is `Found nothing!`. What is going on here and how can I fix this problem?

(Also worth noting: my python path includes both `/path/to/foo_module` and `/path/to` because I am overly thorough/confused.)

Comment: Marking this question as a duplicate makes no sense without the comment from (the red box at the end of) [\[Python.Docs\]: Enum HOWTO - Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#comparisons)

Answer (score -1):

Ah! Your problem is how you're importing `servers.py` from `foo_module/decide.py`: you need to explicitly tell python that `servers.py` is part of the same module and not part of another module. In particular the import statement needs to change:

```
from servers import KnownComputers
```

should become

```
from .servers import KnownComputers
```

Comment: Well that's not a very helpful answer. You haven't told me anything about why python would see `/path/to/foo_module/servers.py` as being a different file from `/path/to/foo_module/servers.py` and import it twice.